# Solve $2x\cos x+(1-x^2)\sin x=0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I can't solve:
$$2x\cos x+(1-x^2)\sin x=0$$
The solution must be $(k-1)\pi<x_k<(k-1)\pi+\frac{\pi}{2}$ for $k=2,3,4,\ldots$

Any hint?

Many thanks!

Comment: Make the equation in terms of $\tan$...

Comment: but i think we must use a numerical method

Comment: Try to use Newton-Raphson Method

Answer (score 3):

The following facts may be helpful.

Note that $\tan x = \frac{2x}{x^2-1}=\frac{2(-x)}{1-(-x)^2}$ by the assumtion and $\tan x=\frac{2\tan \frac x2}{1-\tan^2 \frac x2}$